# Hide Gtk::Notebook page content, without hiding the tab

Tags: gtk3, gtkmm

I've got an unusual situation where I want to hide the content of a notebook page until the notebook tab is clicked. I basically want a state where only the notebook tabs are visible.

The problem is, if I hide a notebook page, then its tab is also hidden. I've tried forcing the height of the content to zero (using `set_size_request`) but that doesn't do it (because `set_size_request` sets the min height, not the maximum.

How can I hide the content of the pages without the tabs disappearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put it in a single-child parent widget, such as a Gtk::Alignment, and hide the child, but not the parent.

Or maybe Gtk::Stack would be simpler:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html